# Webmin (a free VHM) recommend not running it with Apache?

Tags: apache, webmin

I am about to move my sites to VPS (Ubuntu 16, Apache, with Webmin VHM).

In Webmin.com I [came across this article](http://webmin.com/apache.html) that says:

> WARNING : Running Webmin under Apache is almost never necessary unless
>   you are on a very low-memory system that is already running Apache.
>   Doing so will make Webmin slower, break some features and force use of
>   the old ugly UI.

Is it only a bad phrasing? Because I can't think of any reason why Webmin will warm people not to use Webmin and Apache together --- Almost any Webmin user I know, uses Apache (or Nginx) as its server software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can indeed be defined as a bad wording on their side, even though it is technically correct:

Running Webmin ***under*** Apache ***and not*** Running Webmin ***with/and*** Apache. This is referring to whether Webmin is run with it's own HTTP server  on port 10000 ***or*** using Apache.

It is in no way saying that Webmin and Apache should not be run at the same time.